# MongoDB: Getting entries with maximum version-id after grouping

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm rather new to `MongoDB` and I'm trying to create a query which I though would be pretty trivial (well, alteast with `SQL` it would) but I can't get it done.

So have a collection `patients` in this collections a single `patient` is identified using the `id` property. **(NOT mongodbs `_id`!!)** There can be multiple version of a single `patient`, his version is determined by the `meta.versionId` field.

In order to query for all "current versions of patients" I need to get for every `patient` with a specific `id` the one with the maximum `versionId`.

So far I've got this:

```
    AggregateIterable<Document> allPatients = db.getCollection("patients").aggregate(Arrays.asList(
            new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$id")
            .append("max", new Document("$max", "$meta.versionId")))));

    allPatients.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
        @Override
        public void apply(final Document document) {
            System.out.println(document.toJson());
        }
    });
```

Which results in the following output (using my very limited test data):

`{ "_id" : "2.25.260185450267055504591276882440338245053", "max" : "5" }
 { "_id" : "2.25.260185450267055504591276882441338245099", "max" : "0" }`

Seems to work so far, but I need to get the whole `patients` collection. 
Now I only know that for the `id : 2.25.260185450267055504591276882440338245053` the max version is "5" and so on. Of course I could now create an own query for every single entry and sequentially get each `patient` document for a specific `id`/`versionId`-combo from mongodb but this seems like a terrible solution! Is there any other way to get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the columns that you want to retrieve , say patient name , address, etc I guess you can append those columns to the document with value 1.

```
AggregateIterable<Document> allPatients = db.getCollection("patients").aggregate(Arrays.asList(
            new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$id")
            .append("max", new Document("$max", "$meta.versionId")).append("name",1).append("address",1))));
```

Comment: Thats true, but unfortunately I'm dealing with a profile of the [FHIRs patient](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/patient.html) resource which structure is rather complex. So, I'd prefer a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

An approach that could work for you would be to first order the documents getting in the pipeline by the `meta.versionId` field using the **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)** pipeline operator. However, be aware that the **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)** stage has a limit of 100 megabytes of RAM. By default, if it exceeds this limit, **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)**  will produce an error.

To allow for the handling of large datasets, set the `allowDiskUse` option to true to enable **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)** operations to write to temporary files. See the `allowDiskUse` option in **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)** method for details.

After sorting, you can then group the ordered documents, carry out the aggregation using the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** or **[`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last)** operators (depending on the previous sort direction) to get the other fields.

Consider running the following mongo shell pipeline operation as a way of
demonstrating this concept:

**Mongo shell**

```
pipeline = [
    { "$sort": {"meta.versionId": -1}}, // order the documents by the versionId field descending
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$id",
            "max": { "$first": "$meta.versionId" }, // get the maximum versionId
            "active": { "$first": "$active" }, // Whether this patient's record is in active use
            "name": { "$first": "$name" }, // A name associated with the patient
            "telecom": { "$first": "$telecom" }, // A contact detail for the individual
            "gender": { "$first": "$gender" }, // male | female | other | unknown
            "birthDate": { "$first": "$birthDate" } // The date of birth for the individual
            /*
                And many other fields 
            */
        }
    }
]
db.patients.aggregate(pipeline);
```

---

**Java test implementation**

```
public class JavaAggregation {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException {

        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient();
        DB db = mongo.getDB("test");

        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("patients");

        // create the pipeline operations, first with the $sort
        DBObject sort = new BasicDBObject("$sort",
                            new BasicDBObject("meta.versionId", -1)
                        );

        // build the $group operations
        DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$id");
        groupFields.put("max", new BasicDBObject( "$first", "$meta.versionId"));
        groupFields.put("active", new BasicDBObject( "$first", "$active"));
        groupFields.put("name", new BasicDBObject( "$first", "$name"));
        groupFields.put("telecom", new BasicDBObject( "$first", "$telecom"));
        groupFields.put("gender", new BasicDBObject( "$first", "$gender"));
        groupFields.put("birthDate", new BasicDBObject( "$first", "$birthDate"));
        // append any other necessary fields

        DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
        List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList(sort, group);

        AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate(pipeline);

        for (DBObject result : output.results()) {
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like the same thing as above, just with sorting. So I guess there's no possibility to get all fields, except defining them on my own, right?

Comment: @FelixCullen Unfortunately no. Understand the way the pipeline works; When executing a pipeline, MongoDB pipes operators into each other. `“Pipe”` here takes the Linux meaning: the output of an operator becomes the input of the following operator. The result of each operator is a new collection of documents. So when you want to get the fields within a group pipeline the only way is to use the accumulator operators available only in the pipeline at that stage and for the above its either using `$first` or `$last`, depending on the order of the documents entering the pipeline.